# Fantasy book about an empath

Tags: story-identification, books

I read the first few chapters of a book a while ago and cannot remember the title or who it was by. All I can remember is that the main character was an empath, she plays guitar at a gig and is very antisocial, whilst playing at a gig she makes everyone feel happy but can't get to one person as the have a 'dark' vibe around them. Once leaving the gig she senses a other darkness and three guys jump and rape her in an alley, she kills them by using the emotions of their previous victims. Afterwards to faints and falls into a strangers arms. Does anyone have any idea what this book is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [Queen of Shadows](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7863163-queen-of-shadows) by Dianne Sylvan.

The story is about a guitar-playing empath. There's a scene where the protagonist is raped and then kills the perpetrators using her mind. At the end of the chapter she faints away and is taken into the care of a mysterious stranger.

> Shortly after she picked up a guitar, Miranda Grey conquered the
> Austin music scene with a newfound ability to psychically manipulate
> her audience’s emotions. But as her powers outgrow her control, her
> mind is increasingly invaded by haunting secrets and overwhelming
> sadness. Unable to look anyone in the eye, Miranda is fast approaching
> the edge of insanity – with no one to catch her fall…

[image]

> *She stood over them in the now-pouring rain, blood oozing down her
> thighs, her hands fisted at her sides, and ground her emotions into
> them like putting out a cigarette in someone’s arm. She made them feel
> the fear and pain of every woman they’d raped and killed, imagining
> their last thoughts. The women had mothers, daughters, boyfriends
> waiting at home who would never see them again. They had hopes and
> fears and possibilities that Miranda had never had. These pathetic
> little men had taken all of that away. Their hatred for women had made
> them bold.*
>
> *One of them was begging for his life. She stared down at him, and he
> flinched from her eyes, eyes no one had seen in months. He had a wife,
> kids. Please. He offered her anything she wanted if she’d just let him
> go.*
>
> *She stared, feeling nothing. “No.”*